# `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` when executing `list queues` with `rabbitmqadmin`

Tags: python3, rabbitmq

I want to list available queues on a remote RabbitMQ server with the following command:
`rabbitmqadmin --host=a.b.c.com --port=443 --username=user --password=pwd list queues`

But it ends with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 1150, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 494, in main
    method()
  File "/usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 694, in invoke_list
    format_list(self.get(uri), cols, obj_info, self.options)
  File "/usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 523, in get
    return self.http("GET", "%s/api%s" % (self.options.path_prefix, path), "")
  File "/usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 597, in http
    die(json.loads(resp.read())['reason'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried lots of variants of the command: without credentials, with `-k` option... but without success. The error has always been the same.

`nmap` tells me that the host `a.b.c.com` is alive and the port `443` is open.

The error may indicate a problem with python, but how the workaround may look like? Installing another version of rabbitmqadmin (the current one is 3.8.2) or another python version (the current one is 3.8.10)?

I've also downloaded rabbitmqadmin from the remote server as explained here https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html and used it.

The downloaded version was 3.8.19 but it didn't help.

Not sure what is going on behind the scenes that causes this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--ssl` option solved the issue. However the error message was really misleading